# django's get_user_model() only in 1.11 during import time

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-custom-user

I've created this draft of a reusable app: [django-separate-users](https://github.com/bnzk/django-separate-users). It basically works :) But, this code only runs on django 1.11+. The problem is right here, the call to `get_user_model()`: [models.py](https://github.com/bnzk/django-separate-users/blob/master/separate_users/models.py).

The docs state, that in 1.11 "The ability to call `get_user_model()` at import time was added.": 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model

How can I make this code work down to django 1.8? AUTH_USER_MODEL is a string, so it doesnt work? As far as I can see, `get_user_model()` uses django's `apps.get_model('my_app', 'my_model')`, where in django 1.11, it adds a `require_ready` kwarg. Compare [django 1.11](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/contrib/auth/#get_user_model) vs [django 1.10](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/_modules/django/contrib/auth/#get_user_model) get_user_model. Also, the kwarg of `apps.get_model()` was introduced in django 1.11.

---

Here is the code (models.py), simplified:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

UserModel = get_user_model()


class FrontendUser(UserModel):

    objects = FrontendUserManager()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.is_staff = False
        super(FrontendUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

And the (obvious) error in django<1.11:

```
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

Maybe it's simply impossible to achieve?

Comment: did you look on [source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/contrib/auth/#get_user_model) may be it help you?

Comment: must admit, no. but it doesnt help, the problem remains: I cannot load the custom user model, as `Models aren't loaded yet' (see added Error)?